# Scrape Bolded Text with rvest

Tags: html, r, rvest

I am scraping in R with rvest. I am trying to extract a list of dollar signs. Either $, $$, or $$$. The site shows $$$, and bolds in dark black 1, 2, or 3 of the symbols. With my current code, it is drawing $$$ for every single page.

This is an example of the HTML code for the site section (This one has one $ bolded in dark black). I am trying to extract one "$" for this example:

```
<div class = "container">
 <div class = "value">
  <strong>
   " $"
   <span>$$</span>
  </strong>
 </div>
<div class ="label">Price</div>
```

I am currently using code something like this. It is looping through 1000s of similar pages. All are pulling $$$.:

```
html <- read_html(website) # save html from page

text <- html_elements(html, ".value") %>% 
        html_text(trim = T) # save list of text in this section of the page

price <- text[length(text)] # save the price, it is the last text section in the list
```

Comment: Difficult to answer and test when you don't share the website you're trying to scrape.

Comment: Is there something missing? Because if I look at the ouput of that HTML I see that all three dollar signs are bold since they are all in the `<strong>` tag. Is there some CSS code or something that makes the `<span>` non bold?

Comment: If you only want to select the text not inside the `<span>`, you can use the XPath selector `xpath = "//div [@class='value']/strong/text()"`

Comment: Thanks all. Yes, I apologize; I don't want to specify the site I am scraping. @Bas the XPath code works perfectly!